# Resetting the counter when adding a new entry to MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

There are two tables, in one auto-increment id file, in another auto-increment id page. The tables are linked by a key to the id file.

[image: DataBase Schema.]

I want to make in SQL when the id Pres changes, the  id Slide starts with 1. The end result should look like:

[image: example]

How  I should get the end result like this ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When posting, it's important to ask a question, something you seem to have missed here. What is your question? When posting results, it's good to provide sample data and expected results too; and make sure you post them as `text`, not an image. Finally, what have you tried so far? Make sure you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52476580/edit) your question with this information, **don't** post it in the comment.s Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My reputation is too low to comment. But please let me know if this is what you're looking for.

So you basically want to count the number of IdSlides in each presentation.

Using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER` is one way to go:

`SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY IdPres ORDER BY UuidSlide DESC), IdPres
FROM Slide`